# Get a string that contains the integer representation of an enum value

Tags: c#, .net, enums

```
string userTypeId = ((int)ERPSystemUserType.Basic).ToString();

public enum ERPSystemUserType
{
    Basic = 20,
    Upgraded = 30
}
```

if I use `ToString()`, return the enum type's string value, however I want to use the defined `int` value.

Is there any attribute or way, I could use for return string by is number of the enum?
Instead of doing `((int)ERPSystemUserType.Basic).ToString()`.
And don't want to use the Extension, then I have to use to every enum.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899498/is-it-possible-to-cast-enum-to-integer

Comment: No, there is no method for a single value, just cast it to `int`. But why do you need it as string at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast int to enum in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29482/cast-int-to-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: It is not a duplicate of the threads linked. The asker wants a string `"20"`. There's no need to go through an `int`, explicitly.

Comment: There may not be a need but it seems more semantically correct to me to cast to an int and then do ToString on the result.

Comment: After a lot of searching, I did find an older thread, actually: [C# enum value as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444699/c-sharp-enum-value-as-string).

Answer (score 4):

Use `.ToString("D")`. See [Enumeration Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3s1ez6e.aspx).