# C# enum usage in string

Tags: c#, enums

I'm new to C# but trying to use an enum.  The enum is as follows:

```
public enum PARAM : int { ROLL = 1, PITCH, YAW, MAGX, MAGY, MAGZ, BCA, OAT, IAS, TAS, VOLTS, AOA };
```

I'm using it as follows:

```
AhrsCom.setCommand("$out=" + PARAM.PITCH + ",10\n\r");
```

However, it passes the following string to `setCommand(string command)`:

```
"$out=PITCH,10\n\r"
```

Instead of `out=2,10\n\r`, as I thought it would.

Comment: Cast the enum into `int` if you want to use it as an `int`

Comment: use AhrsCom.setCommand("$out=" + (int)PARAM.PITCH + ",10\n\r");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# numeric enum value as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444699/c-sharp-numeric-enum-value-as-string)

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
AhrsCom.setCommand("$out=" + (int)PARAM.PITCH + ",10\n\r");
```

to say you want the number, not the string

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the enum to an `int` to gets it numeric value:

```
AhrsCom.setCommand("$out=" + (int)PARAM.PITCH + ",10\n\r");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast this way:

```
AhrsCom.setCommand("$out=" + (int)PARAM.PITCH + ",10\n\r");
```